# How does local variables actuallly work in lua?

Tags: lua

I know this is very basic question but i'm pretty much confused by the `local` variables & their scope in lua, for instance if i write `local x=12`, it means that the variable `x` is a local variable & it's value is `12`, but instead if i write `local x` & in the next line `x=12`, does this mean the same as in previous case or `x=12` is treated as a global variable?

Comment: Mind-bender: `local x=12  local x=x+11` Two variables: The second has the value 23; The first still has the value 12 but is thereafter inaccessible due to being shadowed by the second.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can think of it as two totally independent things:

1. `local x` creates a "slot" in the local scope to hold a value, i.e. a variable. This variable is named `x`. From that point forward, until you exit that scope, any reference to `x` will refer to that local `x`.
2. `x = 12` puts a value into the variable `x`. If you've previously created a local slot named x, that's where it'll go. If there is no local `x` in scope, it'll go into the global scope.

`local x = 12` is just a shorthand for combining these two things, creating a local variable and assigning it a value at the same time.

So yes, your two scenarios are effectively equivalent.

```
local x
x = 12
```

And

```
local x = 12
```

Do the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

You only use the `local` keyword once per scope, so that second access of `x` in your example will use the local `x`. If you then wish to access the global `x`, you can use `__G.x`

Comment: so u mean to say that in second case `x=12` implies that `local x=12` right ??

Comment: @caesargetit That is not correct. `local x=12` means a new local variable `x`. `x=12` means assign 12 to the nearest previous local `x` or, if none, to the global variable `x`.